# Error starting tomcat java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter

Tags: spring, tomcat10

I'm upgrading my environment and war project from tomcat8.5 and jdk11 to tomcat10 and jdk17.
I have a spring (not spring boot) 4.0.0 project and when I start tomcat, I get this error:

GRAVE: Exception starting filter [encoding-filter]
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.Filter (org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @8c11eee; jakarta.servlet.Filter is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @7106e68e)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4271)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4886)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:845)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:917)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)

gen 16, 2024 4:56:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file

I tried to replace occurrencies of javax.servlet with jakarta...with no luck

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks